# Django admin - custom page

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I would like to create a custom page (template) in my django admin.

The think is I would like to create a page with some charts (basically stats module for dj admin). Is there any way how to create new, blank page in django admin (page not bound to any model) and fill it with my own content (charts, text, images...)?

Also how to add link to this page to django index page (dashboard)?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have you read: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/admin/#adding-views-to-admin-sites ?

Comment: Thanks I will have a look. Sorry for my blindness I had googled wrong phrase.

Comment: No worries. If that lets you get the job done, be sure to answer your own question so it can help others.